# Store language independent strings in Android resources

Tags: android, internationalization, resources

How would I store some language independent values like website address in an Android project. I am currently storing it inside my `strings.xml`. This does not look good as if I add another language and translations, this entry will still have the same value and will be duplicated.

I would also like to get some tips on creating Android projects with I18N in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create the same keys in the translated xml file again. If Android does not find `link` in the German/Spanish/Whatever language file, it will fall back to the original key stored in the default `string.xml`.

I suggest to implement the English version first and after that let someone translate it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know of this feature. So no code change required in such cases.

Comment: The basic idea behind that is obvious in case of the application name. You don't need to put the "Awesome" into all language files.

Comment: You'll also want to tweak your lint settings in preferences to avoid warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

for i18n-format, you can create some resources folder for one local :

```
/res/values     <- default locale
/res/values-fr  <- values for french locale
...
```

For more examples, read documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

For language independent Strings just create a class with constants :

```
public class MyIndependentStrings {

public static final String SOME_STRING = "Value";

}
```

Usage :

```
tvMyTextView.setText(MyIndependentStrings.SOME_STRING);
```

In this case you will use constants and not i18n Strings from ../values/strings.xml

Comment: this way he cannot use them in xml files

Comment: "In this case you will use constants and not i18n Strings from ../values/strings.xml" - I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting language independent strings in:

```
\res\values-nodpi\strings.xml
```